# Fredholm property of linearization of Floer map

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sg.symplectic-geometry

I am reading Audin and Damian's book *"Morse theory and Floer homology"*. In Proposition 8.1.4 which reveals the transversality property of moduli space of solutions of Floer equation, the authors define an operator
$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{aligned}\Gamma:W^{1,p}(\mathbf{R}\times S^1;\mathbf{R}^{2n})\times C_\varepsilon^\infty(H_0)\end{aligned}& \longrightarrow L^p(\mathbf{R}\times S^1;\mathbf{R}^{2n})  \\
(Y,h)& \longmapsto(dF^H)_u(Y)+\operatorname{grad}_uh.
\end{aligned}
$$
Here $C_\varepsilon^\infty(H_0)$ is the space of perturbations of Hamiltonian function $H $, F is the Floer map
$$\begin{aligned}&F:C^\infty(\mathbf{R}\times S^1;W)\longrightarrow C^\infty(\mathbf{R}\times S^1;TW)\\&u\longmapsto\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}+J\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\mathrm{grad}_u(H_t).\end{aligned} $$

My **question** is the exercise 44 of this book. Why is the kernel of $\Gamma$ is not finite-dimensional? I know that the difference between finite-dimensional space and infinite-dimensional space is that unit ball in infinite-dimensional space is not compact. But I don't know how to show it in the exercise. Any hint is welcome!

Comment: *Hint.* They show in Section 8.7c that $(dF^H)_u$ is a Fredholm operator.

Answer (score 1):

They show in Section 8.7.c that $(dF^H)_u$ is a Fredholm operator.

What remains is simple linear algebra (even continuity is irrelevant). Suppose $A: V \times W \to U$ is a linear map, with $B = A|_V$ a Fredholm map and $C = A|_W$ an arbitrary linear map. Then $\ker(A)$ is infinite-dimensional if and only if $W$ is infinite-dimensional.

For consider the projection map $p: \ker(A) \to W$ sending $(v,w)$ to $w$. An element of the domain has $A(v,w) = 0$, so $Bv = -Cw$. Thus $\ker(p) = \ker(B) \times \{0\}$.

Suppose $C$ has finite-dimensional kernel, then $\text{im}(p) = C^{-1}(\text{im}(B))$ has finite codimension in $W$. Because $W$ is infinite-dimensional, it follows that $\ker(A)$ is infinite-dimensional.

Now suppose $\ker(C)$ is infinite-dimensional. Then $0 \times \ker(C) \subset \ker(A)$, so $\ker(A)$ is infinite-dimensional.

On the other hand, if $W$ was finite-dimensional, it is easy to see $A$ remains Fredholm.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's a nice solution!